# Old Android EDGE filter

Tags: filter

[update: sorry guys i couldn't explain. but i somehow managed it. in adobe lightroom, detail tab, when sliding 'masking' in sharpening section i hold'alt' button in keyboard and took screenshot.and cropped that hell screenshot. i think you guys could understand wwhat actually i am trying.]

i have an old android phone where I have a filter called "edges" in built in gallery photo editor. this makes the real photo like this. I can't find this filter in newer android or even in desktop. charrette is a clip art, ignore that.
[image: ds]

Comment: Hello Abdullah. I have closed your question, as it is really not about graphic design, and we cannot assume designers would know the answer to this question any better than non-designers. To be honest, I'm not quite sure what it is you're asking. You can [edit] your question to specify exactly what it is you want, and it will automatically be added to the re-open queue.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Photoshop > `Filter > Filter Gallery > Find Edges`.

I'm afraid what a *phone* may or may not have available may not be very related to graphic design. I, personally, don't know any designers which are *actually* completing any *real* work on their phone.

Comment: please see the update, i tried your method but can't control that filter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download any software you can do it online.

Use the G'MIC* online filters here: https://gmicol.greyc.fr/

Upload an image, then go into the filters and choose *Contours > Gradient Norm*

Adjust the sliders until you get the effect you want. When you're satisfied, click "render full image", then download.

Example

[image]

*Note: I have no affiliation with G'MIC. If you have GIMP (which is a free image editor) you can install the [G'MIC filters as a plugin](https://gmic.eu/) to use directly inside GIMP.

Comment: yes you got it, but i dont feel safe with online tools. (please read the update)

Comment: I already gave you an option that isn't online. See the *Note under the screenshot.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMuaz - why don't you feel safe?  Do you think your work will be stolen?  Do you have an adequate virus checker installed?  The tool mentioned will most likely not retain copies of your image.

Comment: i think my screenshot method is better. thaMks you guys